# Regex for extracting all complex dates formats from a string

Tags: python, regex, date

I have following string:

```
"04-20-2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009; 20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 2 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009; Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009; Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010; 6/2008; 12/2009; 2009; 2010; 31/May/2019; 01/October/2019; 1st April"
```

With Current regex I am able to find all dates format accept two which are 31/May/2019 and 01/October/2019

Current regex which I am using:

```
(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*)?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[a-z\s,.]*(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd)\s,]*)+(?:\d{2,4})+
```

Can anyone help in making a regex for extracting all dates mentioned above. I want to solve this using regex only.

Comment: whats the data source?

Comment: This may help https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I had updated the Question?

Comment: `[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches 0 or more any of: `-, /, t, h, |, s, n, d, r, \s`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dates = """04-20-2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009; 20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 2 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009; Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009; Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010; 6/2008; 12/2009; 2009; 2010; 31/May/2019; 01/October/2019"""

pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(dates.split(';')))


0    2009-04-20
1    2009-04-20
2    2009-04-20
3    2009-04-03
4    2009-03-20
5    2009-03-20
6    2009-03-20
7    2009-03-20
8    2009-03-20
9    2009-03-20
10   2009-03-02
11   2009-03-20
12   2009-03-20
13   2009-03-21
14   2009-03-22
15   2009-02-01
16   2009-09-01
17   2010-10-01
18   2008-06-01
19   2009-12-01
20   2009-01-01
21   2010-01-01
22   2019-05-31
23   2019-10-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @Ani well you tagged pandas so this solution is pretty robust, whats your intended goal? why do you only need regex?

Comment: Lets say in astring if there are more than one date then in that case above code doesnt work for example --- string= "1st April ~ 31st March 2019"

Comment: you should update your question with all your requirements @Ani - in that case you would need a range?